# How to print out an ascii tree of the Linux script files?

Tags: linux, init

I've seen in some posts people posting an ascii tree diagram of the Linux init scripts. You can see what binaries/scripts are called from init, and in what order.

Do you know which tool are they using?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I am actually trying to find one I saw, the moment I find it, I edit and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, it's difficult to say.

You can use `initctl list` to list init scripts, and it shows a list of scripts, status and the process id (if they are running). However it's not in a tree format, just a list.

Answer (score 0):

I use htop which has a tree mode (f5). Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

It might be easier if you could provide a link to what you mean.